# Remove Unfortunately App Has Stopped?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app that opens a webpage in the android browser when the app is launched. It is working fine except after the webpage starts to load I am getting this "Unfortunately App has stopped" message but the page continues to load and I can click "OK" on the message, it goes away and the browser stays open to the page and I can use it as intended. How can I get that message to stop popping up?

Here's the logcat

```
01-28 10:27:01.399: E/Trace(15226): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-28 10:27:01.509: D/AndroidRuntime(15226): Shutting down VM
01-28 10:27:01.509: W/dalvikvm(15226): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b702a0)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.sugarray.nasamobile/com.sugarray.nasamobile.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
01-28 10:27:01.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15226):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 10:28:48.009: I/Process(15226): Sending signal. PID: 15226 SIG: 9
01-28 10:34:26.813: E/Trace(15569): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-28 10:34:26.907: D/AndroidRuntime(15569): Shutting down VM
01-28 10:34:26.907: W/dalvikvm(15569): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b702a0)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.sugarray.nasamobile/com.sugarray.nasamobile.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
01-28 10:34:26.915: E/AndroidRuntime(15569):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MainActivity

```
package com.sugarray.nasamobile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("http://mobile.nasa.gov"); 
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);

   }
public void exit(View view){
    System.exit(0);
}


}
```

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: Is the whole point of your app just to open a webpage?

Comment: @turbo shhh... its opening some top secret Nasa page xD

Answer (score 4):

Just add this line to the beginning of `onCreate()`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

PS: You should learn to read the Logs. They really already contained the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Read the stack trace. It says :

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity  
{com.sugarray.nasamobile/com.sugarray.nasamobile.MainActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
```

You have forgotten to call `super.onCreate()`, as FD_ has already pointed out. As a rule of thumb, most Android methods will require you to call their super methods, especially those in the lifecycle.

*NB: Stack traces are meant for humans to read and are not some alien sign language transliterated to English.* LOL